# Looping Java AudioInputStream

Tags: java, audio

Good day everyone. I have an audio class, that plays a .wav file. But i wanna loop it forever.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class AudioPlayer {{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {

          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.wav"));         
          clip.open(inputStream);
          clip.start(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }).start();  
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the loop facility in the Clip class described [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop%28int%29)?

```
clip.open(inputStream);
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
```